# Why is django not finding any object matching the query, even though object is created

Tags: python, django, django-views, http-status-code-404

HEADSUP: I don't know if this is a duplicate. There are many with similar titles one, but they aren't answering my question. If it is a duplicate, however, please inform me.

I have this model called Item:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() + timedelta(5))
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If you see, Item is referencing a ForeignKey called Task:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() + timedelta(5))
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have a delete view for Item:

```
class DeleteItemView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'function/delete_item.html'
    success_url = reverse('all-items')

    def test_func(self):
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        if item.task.author == self.request.user and not item.task.is_completed:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DeleteItemView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['task'] = Task.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])[0]
        return context
```

The url pattern for the delete view is:

```
    path('task/<int:pk>/item/<int:pk2>/delete/', DeleteItemView.as_view(), name='delete-item'),
```

`pk` is for the Task model and `pk2` is for the Item model.

Now, my problem is this. Whenever I try to go to this delete view, it results in an error, saying there is no item found matching the query (404). And it says `Raised by: function.views.DeleteItemView`. I am at my wits end, spending almost half a day trying to figure this out, but with no success.

Any help or answers will be immensely and greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `pk` and what is `pk2`? Which model are they for exactly? Also you should show your url pattern in the question.

Comment: I have added description on what pk and pk2 (Task model and Item model) and the url pattern. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a lack of understanding of class based views that deal with single objects. Any view that deals with a single object inherits from [`SingleObjectMixin` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin) down the line. `SingleObjectMixin` gets the relevant object using either (or both) the pk or slug passed as keyword arguments to the view.

The name of the kwarg for pk is denoted by the `pk_url_kwarg` which defaults to `pk`, (meaning if there is a kwarg `pk` passed to the view it will be used for getting the object) and the kwarg for the `slug` is denoted by `slug_url_kwarg`.

In your view you deal with *two* objects one `Item` and the other `Task`. And the generic view is supposed to deal with the `Item`. The problem here is you pass the pk for the `Item` as `pk2` and for the `Task` as `pk`! The view of course considers that `pk` is for the instance it needs to deal with and hence you get the error.

One solution would be to interchange the names of the two kwargs, but we can do better than that. `pk` and `pk2` are not very descriptive, yes? Lets change their names to be more descriptive.

In your url pattern, change the names of the captured arguments:

```
path('task/<int:task_pk>/item/<int:item_pk>/delete/', DeleteItemView.as_view(), name='delete-item'),
```

In your view, set `pk_url_kwarg` and also correct the names:

```
class DeleteItemView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'function/delete_item.html'
    success_url = reverse('all-items')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'item_pk'  # set this

    def test_func(self):
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=self.kwargs['item_pk'])
        if item.task.author == self.request.user and not item.task.is_completed:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DeleteItemView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['task'] = Task.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['task_pk'])[0]
        return context
```

In fact one thing to note would be that if the `Task` is the one that is related to the `Item` you don't even *need* to pass it in your url, you can simply write:

```
task = item.task
```

Comment: WOW WOW WOW! That was extremely helpful, as you not only gave a good solution, but you accompanied it with a great explanation. Thank you so much. This has been annoying me for so long. Thanks again!!!!!